# javascript function execute more times when i click with jquery button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try make button with jQuery I call the JavaScript function, but I got problem :

1. after page loaded, first time click on mybutton there is no reaction
2. second click will execute function twice
3. third click will execute function three
   and more

Why my code execute many more ? I just want " **1 click 1 execution JavaScript function**"
my code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function showcase(){
    var foo = function () {
         alert('tutup');
    };
    $('#create-new').on('click',foo);
    return false;
}</script> <button class="button" id="create-new"onclick="return showcase();">show text</button>
```

please help me out this problem

for try my full error code at here http://jsbin.com/ovucer/1/edit

Comment: thx u all.. i get the answer... very helpfull..thx u. **CASE CLOSED**

Comment: show us the right answer ^^

Answer (score 3):

You are registering multiple click event listeners to the element

Every time you click on the button you are adding a new click handler to the button using `showcase` method, it is not needed

```
<button class="button" id="create-new">show text</button>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var foo = function () {
         alert('tutup');
    };
    $('#create-new').on('click',foo);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you bind a `click` event, which calls `showcase()` function, which as well binds a new `click` event, that calls `foo()` method. And the last iteration is repeated every time you click the button. This is sort of recursion working here.

The right way will be to bind a click event a single time, after the element is loaded:

```
<button class="button" id="create-new">show text</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#create-new").on("click", function() {
        alert("tutup");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are registering an onclick function in onclick,

use this:

```
$('#create-new').on('click', function(){ alert('text button'); return false; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're binding the click event twice. Using `onclick` on the HTML and over again, using jQuery `.on()`.

To make your life easier, and as you're using jQuery already, do it just at the document ready event:

```
var foo = function () {
  alert('text button');

  return false;
};

$(function () {
  $('#create-new').on('click',foo);
});
```

And fix your HTML bit, by removing the `onclick`:

```
<button class="button" id="create-new">show text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your  script tag and delete `the onclick event` in the button:

```
var foo = function () {
    alert('tutup');
};
$('#create-new').on('click',foo);
return false;
```